# How to create the link with confirm in yii with CHtml::linkButton

Tags: php, yii, hyperlink

I am using Yii and want to create  a link to delete the item from the database but when i am using the CHtml::linkButton to create url with confirm option its not creating the url just adding # with the current url , I am using the following code

```
CHtml::linkButton(UserModule::t('Delete User'),array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->id),'confirm'=>UserModule::t('Are you sure to delete this item?')))
```

but if i use this without confirm button its working

Comment: You Better to use chtml::ajaxlink.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh1
you write the conform alert in beforeSend function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the sol by using this.

```
echo CHtml::link(UserModule::t('Delete User'),array('delete','id'=>$model->id),array('confirm' => 'Are you sure to delete this item?'));
```